# Catch crash events with Puppeteer running headless

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is there a way to catch chromium page crash events using Puppeteer in headless mode?

The following works only if not in headless mode?:

```
page.once("error", async () => {
   //Do something
});

await page.goto('about:crash');
```

I'm using headless argument to start puppeteer. (To keep WebGL activated)

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
        `--window-size=${width},${height}`,
        '--headless'
    ]
});
```

Added details:
My goal is to test my app behaviour following a crash.

The following does not catch the error:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const width = 1920;
const height = 1080;

(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            `--window-size=${width},${height}`,
            '--headless'
        ]
    });

    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 10000 });
    console.log('page loaded');

    try {
        //page.goto('about:crash');
        page.goto('chrome://crash/')

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`crash has been catched`)
    };
})();
```

And this does but I get a promise rejection that makes my Jest test fail

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const width = 1920;
const height = 1080;

(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            `--window-size=${width},${height}`,
            '--headless'
        ]
    });

    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 10000 });
    console.log('page loaded');

    page.once("error", async () => {
        console.log('crash has been catched')
    })

    //page.goto('about:crash');
    page.goto('chrome://crash/')

})();
```

How can I

1. crash a page,
2. catch the crash error
3. Do some more tests (like
   creating a new page, reloading the page...)

Comment: Do you have a page that crashes Chrome to try this with?

Comment: Aankhen: I added details

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. I tried try, catch but that does not solve my problem. (See added details)

Comment: Thanks for adding the examples. In the first one, you don’t `await` the `goto` inside the `try`, but in any case, I think it crashes and throws an error outside the main loop, before it gets back to the `goto`, so this approach won’t work. In the second example, I don’t get a promise rejection; the error handler is called and nothing more happens, as expected. Is the rejection you get actually a timeout from Jest, which is waiting for the test to return?

Comment: I get the rejection with this example and I'm not using Jest there. You have to wait a bit more then 30 secondes for the unhandled promise rejection to appear. Its a navigation timeout exceeded.

Comment: I don’t see the rejection in the second example, even after two minutes, on Node.JS v10.4.1 and puppeteer 1.5.0. Are your versions different?

Comment: I'm using node v8.9.1 and Puppeteer 1.4.0. That is probably why we dont have the same behaviour. I'll try with updated versions.

Comment: Tried with node v10.6.0 and it solves my issue. I dont have unhandled promise rejection with this version. Thanks Aankhen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch. You can also set a bool variable to know when to close/open a new page. (e.g. reusePageInstance)

Here is an example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var reusePageInstance = true;

(async() => {
  const args = [
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--no-sandbox",
  ];
  const options = {
    args,
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  };

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

  let page

  if (!reusePageInstance) {
    page = await browser.newPage()
  }

  var q = ['http://www.stackoverfllow.com']

  while (q.length > 0) {

    let url = q.shift()
    console.log('Loading Page: ' +' - ' + url)

    try {
      if (reusePageInstance) {
        page = await browser.newPage()
      }

      await page.goto(url, {
        timeout: 10000,
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
      })
      console.log('Page Loaded')

      const html = await page.content();
      // do something

      if (reusePageInstance) {
        await page.close()
      }
      console.log('Page closed')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('**** FAIL ****')
      console.log('Page Load Failed', url)
      console.error(e)
      await page.close()
    }
  }
  await browser.close()

})()
```

Comment: Can you post the Jest test code or snippet? As I think you are not using page.close() and page = await browser.newPage() for when a crash occurred.